# SQuirreL SQL Client interface font too small

Tags: windows, squirrel-sql

I would like to increase the font size of my SQuirreL interface because it's ridiculously small. I can't find the way to do that. Here how it look like:

[image: SQuirreL]

I would like to emphasize that I want to adjust **the interface**, not the font of the SQL, which it's fine and I know how to change it if I wanted to.

Comment: Have you looked at Global Preferences + fonts? Enabling the bottom option appears to give font size choices

Comment: That worked! I had been looking in other window. Thank you.

Comment: @Slumdog, `Global Preferences + fonts` is not available in 3.9.1.  Has it been moved to a different place?

Comment: Hi, I've been on a break for quite a while but I just updated to the latest squirrel-sql-snapshot-20190401_2220-standard.jar and fonts is still there, cheers